# Как построить таблицу из списка?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть список из 56 элементов.

Как сделать из него таблицу из 7 столбцов, чтобы каждый элемент списка ложился в свой столбец?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А в чем собственно проблема? Numpy и Pandas позволяют это делать легко и элегантно:

```
In [68]: lst = np.arange(56).tolist()

In [69]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(lst).reshape(-1, 7)).add_prefix("col")

In [70]: df
Out[70]:
   col0  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6
0     0     1     2     3     4     5     6
1     7     8     9    10    11    12    13
2    14    15    16    17    18    19    20
3    21    22    23    24    25    26    27
4    28    29    30    31    32    33    34
5    35    36    37    38    39    40    41
6    42    43    44    45    46    47    48
7    49    50    51    52    53    54    55

In [71]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(lst).reshape(7, -1).T).add_prefix("col")

In [72]: df
Out[72]:
   col0  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6
0     0     8    16    24    32    40    48
1     1     9    17    25    33    41    49
2     2    10    18    26    34    42    50
3     3    11    19    27    35    43    51
4     4    12    20    28    36    44    52
5     5    13    21    29    37    45    53
6     6    14    22    30    38    46    54
7     7    15    23    31    39    47    55
```